# How to load my JSON locally?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

I want to have a object holding the names and links of multiple pictures. I want my function to parse the JSON and make it into an object. My HTML is

```
<button type = "button" id = "easy" onclick = "displayEasy()"> Easy </button>
```

My javascript is

```
var easyMode = JSON.parse("images/picObject.json").imagesEasy;

function displayEasy(){

    var objLen = easyMode.length; // number of elements in object
    var rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * objLen) + 1); //random number
    var imgSrc = easyMode[rand].name; //answer string

    document.getElementById("image").src = imgSrc; //change image src
}
```

My JSON file is

```
{   
    "imagesEasy":[
    {"name": "first aid", "imgSrc": "http://brainden.com/images/aid-rebus-puzzle.gif"},
    {"name": "once in a blue moon", "imgSrc": "http://brainden.com/images/blue-moon-pictogram.gif"},
    {"name": "for instance", "imgSrc": "http://brainden.com/images/word-picture-puzzle.gif"},
    {"name": "green with envy", "imgSrc": "http://brainden.com/images/green-envy.gif"},
    {"name": "broken promise", "imgSrc": "http://brainden.com/images/broken-promise.gif"},
    {"name": "a friend in need", "imgSrc": "http://brainden.com/images/friend-need.gif"},
    {"name": "travel over seas", "imgSrc": "http://brainden.com/images/overseas.gif"},
    {"name": "man overboard", "imgSrc": "http://brainden.com/images/man-overboard.gif"},
    {"name": "ready for anything", "imgSrc": "http://brainden.com/images/ready-anything.gif"},
    {"name": "no one to blame", "imgSrc": "http://brainden.com/images/blame.gif"},
    {"name": "space invaders", "imgSrc": "http://brainden.com/images/space-invaders-rebus.gif"},
    {"name": "small talk", "imgSrc": "http://www.fun-with-words.com/images/rebus/r1037.gif"},
    {"name": "falling asleep", "imgSrc": "http://www.fun-with-words.com/images/rebus/r1001.gif"},
    {"name": "jack in a box", "imgSrc": "http://www.fun-with-words.com/images/rebus/r1029.gif"}
    ],
    "imageMed":[
    {"name": "fair and square", "imgSrc": "https://3.bp.blogspot.com/--R4Vm3cF3t0/UcgqjnwFSXI/AAAAAAAAGsU/L0VFY2Y_89I/s1600/Rebus-Phrase-Puzzle.gif"},
    {"name": "circle of friends", "imgSrc": "https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-_SMwfIispCg/UcgrMJL6Y_I/AAAAAAAAGsc/Qbanv1nRWBU/s1600/Rebus-Image-Brain-Teaser.gif"},
    {"name": "iron curtain", "imgSrc": "https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-dw88zKllR1A/Ud7qF2feiII/AAAAAAAAG1g/xdnFizCK_Sk/s1600/Rebus.gif"},
    {"name": "get up and go", "imgSrc": "https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-g4-ozrzyWMc/UZfJPps9JCI/AAAAAAAAGY8/8QCkBBH62b4/s1600/Rebus.gif"},
    {"name": "robin hood", "imgSrc": "https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-xYGAd4YhmVU/UHGLGLQgj0I/AAAAAAAADyc/35zptnZfHwA/s1600/picture-puzzle.png"},
    {"name": "side show", "imgSrc": "http://www.fun-with-words.com/images/rebus/r1014.gif"},
    {"name": "tickled pink", "imgSrc": "http://www.fun-with-words.com/images/rebus/r1043.gif"},
    {"name": "downright stupid", "imgSrc": "http://www.fun-with-words.com/images/rebus/r1070.gif"},
    {"name": "split personality", "imgSrc": "http://www.fun-with-words.com/images/rebus/r1069.gif"}
    ],
    "imageHard":[
    {"name": "scatter brain", "imgSrc": "https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-nKul-OXMRmk/URKLCStSZbI/AAAAAAAAFrQ/1Xd2WdRh9J4/s1600/Hard-Rebus-Riddle.jpg"},
    {"name": "summary", "imgSrc": "https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-KRPuXuAIC4c/UHGK-fKqSvI/AAAAAAAADw8/73vHbELom5s/s1600/Funny-Rebus-Puzzle.gif"},
    {"name": "painless operation", "imgSrc": "http://www.fun-with-words.com/images/rebus/r1054.gif"},
    {"name": "the wrong side of the stick", "imgSrc": "http://www.fun-with-words.com/images/rebus/r1098.gif"},
    {"name": "back to square one", "imgSrc": "http://www.fun-with-words.com/images/rebus/r1018.gif"},
    {"name": "moral support", "imgSrc": "http://www.fun-with-words.com/images/rebus/r1076.gif"},
    {"name": "beaten black and blue", "imgSrc": "http://www.fun-with-words.com/images/rebus/r1063.gif"}
    ]
}
```

For some reason it is saying I have an unexpected token i in JSON at 0 at anonymous. I dont see any character "i" and Im getting frustrated.

Comment: `"images/picObject.json"` is not a valid json string. `JSON.parse` expects a json string not a path.

Comment: `"images/picObject.json"` is not valid JSON.  It sounds like you're actually looking for AJAX.

Comment: lol so I cant put a link there?

Comment: No, just a string of JSON. Google an Ajax tutorial to get started on how to retrieve the JSON string.

Comment: No, you have to load the content using some other way and then pass the content to `JSON.parse`.

Comment: would it be bad practice to put a string that long on there

Comment: yeah it would. alright thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

You can load your json using [jQuery](https://jquery.com/)

```
var easyMode;
$.getJSON("images/picObject.json", function(data) {
    console.log(data); // parsed json
    easyMode = data.imagesEasy;
});
```

More : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/